# What's the difference between libstdc++ and libstdc++6?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, libstdc++

I happened to make a Xcode project for an open source project from the scratch (WebRTC AppRTCDemo). I read the build script file (.ninja) and configured Xcode build settings, over 10 hours..... I failed many times because of link errors related with C++ Standard Library. It has many dependent libraries(.a).

Finally, I found that it requires not `libstdc++` but `libstdc++6`.

What's the difference between?

Isn't it basically the same?

How come dependent archives could require `libstdc++6`? Could one specify libstd++ version 6 in the compile time?

By the way, with the successfully built executable, I got EXC_BAD_ACCESS when `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()` called.

Xcode 5.1.1.

[image: This is my library selection popup. Only libstdc++ and libstdc++6.]

Comment: Is libstdc++ a different version, maybe version 5?  My system has libstdc++5 and libstdc++6 on it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, libstdc++ versions are connected with gcc versions.
libstdc++6 is a lib from gcc 4.x.x, and previous version is from gcc 3.x.x. As @pzed mentioned, your version of libstdc++ is probably 5.

[Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.how_to_set_paths) is some documentation.